# Permission denied (13)

Tags: samba, clonezilla

I am using Clonezilla 2.2.3-10. When trying to mount via `samba`, I get permission denied (13). I am able to connect via Windows XP, by simply entering the ip + share name

```
\\192.168.1.240\MyShareName
```

I am asked by credentials and I am able to access the share.

Going through Clonezilla, it tries to mount with the following:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.0.240/MyShareName /home/partimag -o username=myusername
```

and I receive the permission denied error.
Any help would be appropriated.

Comment: As you've written it, the IP address in the CloneZilla mount syntax is different from the IP address used in Windows XP.  Is this actually the case or is this a typo?

Comment: Not a typo. In clonezilla, its prompts you for the info and creates the command. I don't have control over how clonezilla mounts the share, other than plugging in the info e.g. ip address, share name etc..